# Monitoring network activity with functional website tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, functional-testing, robotframework

### My Situation

I'm trying to automate the testing of a website's third party tracking and bidding integrations. The best way for me to do that is by opening a browser, visiting certain pages and inspecting some of the network activity.

### The only solution?

Currently Chrome dev tools seem to be the only "one product solution" that has an API for both browser automation and network monitoring. I can write something custom and keep it maintained, but I wanted to explore options before I do.

### What options do I have?

Anything else (like Selenium2) I would need to proxy all requests in to another web service and do the monitoring there... sounds like a pain, but if there is something already out there to do that, then great.

I like some of the functional testing frameworks out there, such as the robotframework, as it solves most of the problems I'm going to face with starting something from scratch, but nothing seems to mention the kind of thing I'm looking for.

I find this incredibly surprising as it seems like it should be a common problem. Am I looking at this the wrong way? Is there a solution out there that I can use? Or does this require something a bit custom?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ChromeDriver and its performance logs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log) to get the Network details out of the automated environment.

Answer (score 0):

In our scenario, we need to open specific url and validate the different calls made and validate request params, cookies also response and cookies headers etc.

I have used browsermob proxy to capture this network traffic.

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815810/2671038):