# Robot Framework - Any ideas on how to capture http requests while a test suite/case is running?

Tags: python-requests, robotframework, browsermob-proxy

I'm looking to capture specific network traffic while my tests are running. 
Currently, I am aware of the following libraries that can  be integrated with robot framework: 
- Requests 
- browsermobproxy

IS it possible to capture network traffic while running robot tests?

Answer (score 0):

I have used browsermob proxy to capture this network traffic.

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815810/2671038):